# Restrict the date on second CJuiDatePicker based on selected date in first CJuiDatePicker

Tags: date, yii, widget, datepicker

I'm using CJuiDatePicker for selecting a date. I'm creating a page to manage holiday, consists of Holiday Name, Holiday From Date, Holiday To Date. From and To use CJuiDatePicker. I'd like to make the Holiday To Date field to be larger than Holiday From Date, for example, Holiday From Date field is 2013-11-12, then Holiday To Date field's dates before 2013-11-12 is disabled and cannot be chosen.

Below is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'holiday_date_from'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php
                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                    'model'       => $model,
                    'attribute'   => 'holiday_date_from',
                    'options'     => array('dateFormat'  => 'dd-mm-yy',
                        'mode'        => 'focus',
                        'changeMonth' => 'true',
                        'showAnim'    => 'slideDown',
                        'changeYear'  => 'true',
                        'yearRange'   => '1920:2013',
                        'onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                            $("#holiday_date_to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                        }',
                    ),
                    'htmlOptions' => array('id' => 'holiday_date_from','class' => 'input-medium', 'style' => 'height: 20px')
                ));?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'holiday_date_from'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'holiday_date_to'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php
                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                    'model'       => $model,
                    'attribute'   => 'holiday_date_to',
                    'options'     => array('dateFormat'  => 'dd-mm-yy',
                        'mode'        => 'focus',
                        'changeMonth' => 'true',
                        'showAnim'    => 'slideDown',
                        'changeYear'  => 'true',
                        'yearRange'   => '1920:2013',
                        'onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                            $("#holiday_date_from").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                        }',
                    ),
                    'htmlOptions' => array('id' => 'holiday_date_to','class' => 'input-medium', 'style' => 'height: 20px')
                ));?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'holiday_date_to'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, the second cjuidatepicker won't disable. I tried to use alert("testing") inside onClose event, but it won't trigger. I also used onChange instead of onClode but failed too. What went wrong anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply try with the right syntax, e.g. :

```
'onClose' => 'js:function (selectedDate) { $("#holiday_date_to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate); }',
```

or :

```
'onClose' => new CJavaScriptExpression('function (selectedDate) { $("#holiday_date_to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate); }'),
```

Comment: Oh my god! How foolish of me. It's supposed to be an array. Thanks for the answer.